# Why the listviewitem's BackColor doesn't work?

Tags: c#, winforms, listviewitem

In this question, the `BackColor` doesn't work. My codes like this:

```
ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem();
item1.SubItems.Clear();
item1.SubItems[0].Text = "english";
item1.SubItems.Add("22");
item1.SubItems.Add("0.5");
item1.BackColor = Color.Red;
item1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
this.listView1.Items.Add(item1);
```

In the Form1.cs[design], it works like this:

[image]

But when I run the program, it doesn't work, like this:

[image]

Comment: I add the  item1.UseItemStyleForSubItems = true.Also i changed the ForeColor.,But it doesn't work too.And I set the BckColor as Gold,In Form1.cs[design],it work,I can see the item's BackColor becoming Gold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, my friend:

```
ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem();
item1.SubItems.Clear();
item1.SubItems[0].Text = "english";
item1.SubItems.Add("22");
item1.SubItems.Add("0.5");
item1.BackColor = Color.Red;
item1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
item1.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
this.listView1.Items.Add(item1);
```

Comment: I just try,but it doesn't work.I am finding others solutions,I think maybe the wrong is happening with the view or the format of listview.though thank your help.

Comment: I just find the listview.enabled was set as false. so careless